# Работа со сценами Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d

Всем привет, как загрузить сцену с дефолтными настройками и данными?
SceneManager.LoadScene("sceneName"); загружает сцену, но это работает только при первом запуске, затем если повторить эту процедуру после того, как немного поиграешь, он загрузит сцену с твоим прогрессом в прошлый раз

Comment: Что значит "с твоим прогрессом в прошлый раз"? .LoadScene загружает сцену как раз с начальными настройками, но если у вас , например, статическая переменная здоровья не обнулена - так такие вещи надо ручками приводить к дефолтным значениямю

Comment: Уже разобрался, думал что для этого есть отдельная функция в Unity, но спасибо за ответ.